# Dependencies list for a PHP project?

Tags: php, maven, dependencies

is there any way to generate a dependency list for a php project with maven?  If not, how can I generate the dependencies list?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can manage dependencies with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)

You can use Composer with any automated system to deploy applications easily.

You can read more about it on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: `mvn dependency:list`

Check out: `mvn dependency:help`